# react-virtualized - how do I use this as a true infinite scroller

Tags: react-virtualized

I can't find any code example or docs that answers this:

- Achieve almost complete infinite scroll -> unknown # of items, but there is a finite amount that may be infeasible to compute beforehand - e.g. at some point the list needs to stop scrolling
- Can I trigger first load of data from within InfiniteScroller/List - it seems you need to pass in a data source that is populated with initial page

I am using this example:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/creatingAnInfiniteLoadingList.md

and:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.example.js

along with CellMeasurer for dynamic height:
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/CellMeasurer/CellMeasurer.DynamicHeightList.example.js

The docs for InfiniteLoader.rowCount say:
"Number of rows in list; can be arbitrary high number if actual number is unknown."

So how do you indicate there are no more rows.

If anyone can post an example using setTimeout() to simulate dynamic loaded data, thanks.  I can likely get CellMeasurer working from there.

**Edit**

This doesn't work the way react-virtualized creator says it should or the infinite loading example implies.

Calls:

- render(): rowCount = 1
- _rowRenderer(index = 0)
- _isRowLoaded(index = 0)
- _loadMoreRows(startIndex = 0, stopIndex = 0)
- _rowRenderer(index = 0)
- end

Do I need to specify a batch size or some other props?

```
class HistoryBrowser extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props,context,updater)
    {
        super(props,context,updater);
        this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
        this.eventEmitter.extend(this);
        this.state = {
            history: []
        };
        this._cache = new Infinite.CellMeasurerCache({
            fixedWidth: true,
            minHeight: 50
        });
        this._timeoutIdMap = {};
        _.bindAll(this,'_isRowLoaded','_loadMoreRows','_rowRenderer');

    }


    render()
    {
        let rowCount = this.state.history.length ? (this.state.history.length + 1) : 1;
        return <Infinite.InfiniteLoader
            isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
            loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
            rowCount={rowCount}
        >
            {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) =>
                <Infinite.AutoSizer disableHeight>
                    {({ width }) =>
                        <Infinite.List
                            ref={registerChild}
                            deferredMeasurementCache={this._cache}
                            height={200}
                            onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                            rowCount={rowCount}
                            rowHeight={this._cache.rowHeight}
                            rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
                            width={width}
                        />}
                </Infinite.AutoSizer>}
        </Infinite.InfiniteLoader>
    }

    _isRowLoaded({ index }) {
        if (index == 0 && !this.state.history.length)
            // No data yet, force load
            return false;
    }

    _loadMoreRows({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
        let self = this;
        for (let i = startIndex; i <= stopIndex; i++) {
            this.state.history[startIndex] = {loading: true};
        }

        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            delete this._timeoutIdMap[timeoutId];

            for (let i = startIndex; i <= stopIndex; i++) {
                self.state.history[i] = {loading: false, text: 'Hi ' + i };
            }

            promiseResolver();
        }, 10000);

        this._timeoutIdMap[timeoutId] = true;

        let promiseResolver;

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            promiseResolver = resolve;
        });
    }

    _rowRenderer({ index, key, style }) {
        let content;
        if (index >= this.state.history.length)
            return <div>Placeholder</div>
        else if (this.state.history[index].loading) {
            content = <div>Loading</div>;
        } else {
            content = (
                <div>Loaded</div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <Infinite.CellMeasurer
                cache={this._cache}
                columnIndex={0}
                key={key}
                rowIndex={index}
            >
                <div key={key} style={style}>{content}</div>
            </Infinite.CellMeasurer>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [recipe you linked to](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/creatingAnInfiniteLoadingList.md) should be a good starting place. The main thing its missing is an implementation of `loadNextPage` but that varies from app to app based on how your state/data management code works.

> Can I trigger first load of data from within InfiniteScroller/List - it seems you need to pass in a data source that is populated with initial page

This is up to you. IMO it generally makes sense to just fetch the first "page" of records without waiting for `InfiniteLoader` to ask for them- because you know you'll need them. That being said, if you give `InfiniteLoader` a `rowCount` of 1 and then return false from `isRowLoaded` it should request the first page of records. There are tests confirming this behavior in the react-virtualized GitHub.

> The docs for InfiniteLoader.rowCount say: "Number of rows in list; can be arbitrary high number if actual number is unknown."
>
> So how do you indicate there are no more rows.

You stop adding +1 to the `rowCount`, like the markdown file you linked to mentions:

```
// If there are more items to be loaded then add an extra row to hold a 
loading indicator.
  const rowCount = hasNextPage
    ? list.size + 1
    : list.size
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for prompt answer, and for react-virtualized!
Having another stab shortly and will update here.

Comment: Link to a Fiddle or something I can run. I don't like debugging problems by text code snippets. Too inefficient. :)

Comment: Thanks, I may do that next week.  I've switched to react-infinite-scroller for a temp solution as I don't want to spend days on this right now, holding up a release.

Comment: @brianvaughn In the recipe, what is the `MyComponent` function? It looks like a render method but it has custom parameters.

Comment: It's a React component. The properties are ones that you would inject from whatever state-management approach you were using for loading external data (e.g. could be Redux, or component `state` in a parent component)